# Declaração de variáveis no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Estou com uma dúvida referente a criação de variáveis no Python utilizando o PyCharm, sempre quando declaro uma variável é exibido um sublinhado verde e a mensagem que aparece é:

> Typo: In Word '{Nome da Variável}'

O que é necessário fazer para que isso suma e eu não precise ficar salvando em level-dictionary ou dando "Rename"?

Comment: Bruno, este link te ajudará, em inglês: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360006338380-Why-does-PyCharm-say-Typo-in-word-SOLVED-

Comment: Digitar o nome certo da variável?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na realidade esse "problema" não está relacionado com a "declarção de variáveis no python", é apenas uma especie de preciosismo do pycharm, algum tempo atrás eu achava interessante essa feature, mas depois que entrei para um time que optou por nomear as variáveis em portugues, cheguei a conclusão que essa feature acaba mais atrapalhando do que ajudando.

Para desabilitar isso no pycharm vá em file/settings, na lupa procure por "spelling" e desabilite typo.

Veja a figura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]